# How to enable audio source in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add some sound to my unity practice project and I have applied the sound and prepared the script necessary for it... but now whenever I am testing it through Unity player audio is not working.. each time I am getting this error log.

> "Can not play a disabled audio source UnityEngine.AudioSource:Play()
>   coinhandler:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at
>   Assets/Script/coin/coinhandler.cs:24)"

My Coinhandler.cs script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class coinhandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform particles;
    public AudioSource coinCollectS;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            coinCollectS.Play ();
        {
            Instantiate (particles, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -0.2f), Quaternion.identity);
            shooterMain.IncreaseSpeed ();
            shooterMain.increasePoint ();
            GameObject.FindWithTag ("points").GetComponent<Text>().text = shooterMain.getPoints ().ToString ();  
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your AudioSource variable is not initialized with an actual AudioSource. Did you linked an AudioSource in Unity editor? Also, is this script on an object that is already created in the editor or do you instantiate from a prefab during execution ? Or something else ?

Comment: @Pac0 I have applied Background sound which is working correctly... And for coin collect sound I have 1st created empty game object then added Audio source component to it and dropped my audio file to that component and moved it to prefab folder then i have edited my cionhandler.cs script which is mentioned above then by just selecting the coin prefab i have dropped the audio prefab to the Coin collect s field in cionhandler.cs script component which is applied to coin prefab.

Comment: @Pac0 I've tried dragging the coin prefab to the Hierarchy panel and then there I've added the sound source object to this cionhandler.cs script and applied now the audio is being play for this separate coin on given condition but not for other coins which is being spawn by the another c# script.

Comment: So this means that the sound was probably not added to the prefab itself. You should try updating your prefab so that the sound is already attached to the AudioSource. Otherwise, you can also attach the sound by code, but in your case, the prefab option should work and be the simplest.

Comment: @Pac0 I tried a lot but i am not getting where i am doing it wrong... please take a look at these screen shots if there is anything wrong. [screen1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6vb952gx3mr6m6/Coin.PNG?dl=0) [screen2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7a7a22hehor4g5/coinhandlerc%23.PNG?dl=0) [screen3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5ycnflbjtjg0a6/soundCoin.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Can't try or suggest more precisely until this week-end, no access to unity right now. In the mean time, maybe someone else could help you, I hope.

Comment: @Pac0 Okay Thanks... :)